# how to make table columns as node in d3 js?

Tags: angular, svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed, d3-force

[image: Table with nodes]

I am new to d3.js. How can I make html draggable table and connect columns with SVG line. The above picture is the exact requirement what I looking for. I am using angular 12 and d3.js 7.2.1.

Comment: What do you need exactly? A path for an SVG line from one point to another?

Comment: I need to create a table and each column of table have an input and output node. The main problem is how to create a table in d3.js and How to make it each column as node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. What do you have right now? Can you post some code and point to a specific problem you experience?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Actually I am not started I have no idea how to do it. First problem I am facing is that how to create a table using svg. Second is How to draw a path for connecting table columns.

Comment: What is your data model? Can you post a JSON?

Comment: "tables" = [
        {
            "name": "Table 1",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "Col 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Col 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Table 2",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "Col 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Col 2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Col 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

Comment: can we show 2 draggable tables with this JSON in svg using d3.js.

Comment: I think you are asking too many questions in one post. First try to build a demo with empty boxes (don't show columns and table titles), then render table data inside boxes, then try to connect boxes with lines. You can find a lot of answers to all of those issues on SO